# can anyone check why my code error like this?

Tags: python, stack

```
self.items == []
AttributeError: 'stack' object has no attribute 'items'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Documents\belajar python new\belajar py\tugasstack.py", line 67, in <module>
    s = stack()
  File "c:\Users\pc\Documents\belajar python new\belajar py\tugasstack.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.items == []
AttributeError: 'stack' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: now my code error like this 'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: You need to post your code that's giving the error rather than just the error message. Show us the entire function.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you shared, the issue seems to be with the line `self.items == []` in the `__init__` method of the `stack` class.

The `==` operator is used for comparison, but in this case, it appears that you intended to use the assignment operator `=`  instead. So, instead of `self.items == []`, it should be `self.items = []`.

Here's the corrected code snippet

```
class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []  # Use assignment operator (=) instead of comparison operator (==)
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` on your first line is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator. To assign an empty list to `self.items`, you want to do this:

```
self.items = []
```

But the correct constructor for a `stack` object that initializes an empty list would be something like this:

```
class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    # Rest of your stack methods to follow here
```